# How can I run uncompiled Spark Scala/spark-shell code as a Dataproc job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

Normally, if I'm using Scala for Spark jobs I'll compile a jarfile and submit it with `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark`, but sometimes for very lightweight jobs I might be using uncompiled Scala code in a notebook or using the `spark-shell` REPL, where I assume a SparkContext is already available.

For some of these lightweight use cases I can equivalently use PySpark and submit with `gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark` but sometimes I need easier access to Scala/Java libraries such as directly creating a `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` object inside of map functions. Is there any easy way to submit such "spark-shell" equivalent jobs directly from a command-line using Dataproc Jobs APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, there isn't a specialized top-level Dataproc Job type for uncompiled Spark Scala, but under the hood, `spark-shell` is just using the same mechanisms as `spark-submit` to run a specialized REPL driver: `org.apache.spark.repl.Main`. Thus, combining this with the `--files` flag available in `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark`, you can just write snippets of Scala that you may have tested in a `spark-shell` or notebook session, and run that as your entire Dataproc job, assuming `job.scala` is a local file on your machine:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster ${CLUSTER} \
    --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main \
    --files job.scala \
    -- -i job.scala
```

Just like any other file, you can also specify any Hadoop-compatible path in the `--files` argument as well, such as `gs://` or even `hdfs://`, assuming you've already placed your `job.scala` file there:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster ${CLUSTER} \
    --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main \
    --files gs://${BUCKET}/job.scala \
    -- -i job.scala

gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster ${CLUSTER} \
    --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main \
    --files hdfs:///tmp/job.scala \
    -- -i job.scala
```

If you've staged your job file onto the Dataproc master node via an init action, you'd use `file:///` to specify that the file is found on the cluster's local filesystem instead of your local filesystem where you're running gcloud:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster ${CLUSTER} \
    --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main \
    --files file:///tmp/job.scala \
    -- -i job.scala
```

Note in all cases, the file becomes a local file in the working-directory of the main driver job, so the argument to "-i" can just be a relative path to the filename.